# SQL server query : how to check value within range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In application I am working on.

I have to input from user through excel and first put it in temporary sql table & then from temporary table to final target table.

My query is failing while putting data from temporary table to target table.
Because some values present in temporary table are out of range of columns in target table.

How can I check if values present in temporary table are within range of column of target table?

I have to check like this

```
20 < len(temporary_table.column1) < 50
```

or is there any better way

Comment: `My query is failing while putting data from temporary table to target table.` .put your query here

Comment: Why are your database constraints not being used in Excel ?

Comment: Try 20< Len(col) and 50 > len(col)...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How is the valid range for the target table defined?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL server you can use below query for data checking.

```
temporary_table.column1 between 20 and 50
```

If you are looking based on the column max length. For example, your columns have datatype `varchar(100)` then you can use the condition like this

```
where len(temporary_table.column1)<=100
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the above answer you can just use col_length instead of hard coding the value on the target column. This makes it more automated and less prone to mistakes (entering a value mistakenly)

```
  where len(temporary_table.column1) <= COL_LENGTH ( 'target_table' , 'column1' )
```